# Why is this XSLT max simulated function not working

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, max

I am not much into xslt, so I am following some well known pattern for simulate max function for xslt 1.0.

**EDIT:**
I know the thread subject may be confusing, I am not trying to build a function, but rather simulating the same behavior

That is, I have the following xml:

```
<cards>
<card><updated>2013-05-19T16:18:59Z</updated></card>
<card><updated>2013-05-19T20:41:59Z</updated></card>
<card><updated>2013-05-19T18:30:59Z</updated></card>
</cards>
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
max-updated:2013-05-19T20:41:59Z
```

this is the xslt, but it's just not working as expected:

```
<xsl:template match="cards">
   max-updated:<xsl:value-of select="card[not(../card[updated] &gt; updated)]/updated"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but the output is:

```
max-updated:2013-05-19T16:18:59Z
```

and it seems to always retrieve the first node.

I know that I could first sort ordering and then get first (or last) position element, but I am more interested on knowing what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 doesn't provide greater-than or less-than comparisons on strings: it converts both strings to numbers (giving NaN) and comparing NaN to NaN always gives false.

The only way to compare strings for magnitude in XSLT 1.0 is xsl:sort - sort the elements and choose the first/last.

Or move to XSLT 2.0.